# How to use GString substitution within '' for json

Tags: json, groovy, gstring

I commonly use `''` for json, for example

```
'{"key":"value"}'
```

or

```
'''
  {"key":"value"}
'''
```

I have a case in a test where I want to substitute part of this with another string, for example:

```
'{"key":"${value}"}'
```

Is there a way to make this work? The enclosing `''` are turning off the substitution.

Thanks!

Comment: Use slashy string. `/{"key":"${value}"}/`

Comment: Thanks @dmahapatro.  This inspired me to  have another look at the classes.  Link added to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use """ string to expand $variables while retaining "

```
def value=123;
def temp="""{"key":"${value}"}"""
assert  temp== '{"key":"123"}'
```

Here is the link to various [Stringy classes](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_string_summary_table) in groovy and their comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Going with double quotes to declare the GString and escaping the inner double quotes will do it:

```
"{\"key\":\"${value}\"}"
```

You can also do away with the inner curlies for some brevity:

```
"{\"key\":\"$value\"}"
```

A little clunky. That could be cleaned up by using sprintf() instead.

Comment: Maybe this can help -> I had a problem in using GString while populating a Map to be used as json in http request. `["total": "${price}"]` generates error while translating into json and using result as HTTP POST request (even if `JsonOutput.prettyPrint( JsonOutput.toJson( __mapName__))` output a correctly formatted JSON ), while `["total": "${price}".toString()]` solved the problem.